# How to disable tabbed browsing, toolbar and address bar in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

[image]

I want to driver chrome with web page only.

Comment: Please give some more information and format your question properly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

disable address bar

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--app=http://www.google.com"); 
driver = new ChromeDriver (options);
```

check more chrome options [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: How about I don't want to hide address bar and don't don't google.com to start with. Just the blank google chrome.

Comment: @vChen, can we achieve the same for Firefox browser ?

Comment: i dont think so.... since no body build for that features yet. i dunnowhy it's just not appropriate for firefox (geckodriver) i guess....

Answer (score 0):

For people using Firefox, it's also possible on Firefox 71+:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--kiosk")
options.add_argument("https://godotengine.org")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```