# Remove address bar in IE with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I can't hide the address bar using selenium

I have read about selenium's capabilities with IE but I can't find the specific one

I hope to have an IE window without the address bar using selenium integrated with java

This is my code:

```
public class SeleniumIE {

static WebDriver visor = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SeleniumIE\\IEDriverServer_Win32_3.14.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
    //commented lines do not work
    //options.setCapability("NoNavBar", false);
    //options.setCapability("toolbars", false);
    visor = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
    visor.get("https://www.google.com/");
    visor.quit();
}  
}
```

Comment: How about just use `sendKeys(Keys.F11)` to open the browser full-screen without any toolbars. But, make sure you maximize the browser this step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Robot class to maximize the window by activating the F11 key. IE does not show any toolbars when it is maximized.

```
   Robot r = new Robot();
   r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F11);
   r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F11)
```

Alternatively, Selenium does have capabilities that allow for browser maximization:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: I need to see the browser window in a similar way to what app mode looks like in chrome. In chrome the option used is --app

Comment: I am not sure about IE, but you can use Chrome and launch it with arguments to get rid of the toolbars, search bar, etc.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46233162/how-to-disable-tabbed-browsing-toolbar-and-address-bar-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: In chrome it is possible but I need to use internet explorer

Comment: `.maximize()` doesn't remove the address bar.

Comment: It doesn't. It hides it.

Answer (score 0):

You could send key stroke with F11 to make IE11 run in full screen.

Or I think **[kiosk mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/154780/how-to-use-kiosk-mode-in-microsoft-internet-explorer)** can meet your requirement.

> When you run Internet Explorer in Kiosk mode, the Internet Explorer title bar, menus, toolbars, and status bar are not displayed and Internet Explorer runs in Full Screen mode.

When you run `iexplore -k page`, IE will start in **kiosk mode**. You could check [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/459775/how-can-i-launch-a-browser-with-no-window-frame-or-tabs-address-bar) and [this blog](http://www.seleniuminaction.com/tag/kiosk/) for more information.